# Nodejs application (Developed using typescrpt not in javascript) deployment issue on Firebase using "firebase serve" command

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase

Trying to deploy nodejs API on google cloud i.e. firebase and getting following error.
Steps :

1. ran tsc src\index inside functions folder for compiling typescript file.
2. Ran "firebase serve" (Error 1)also tried "firebase serve --only functions,hosting" (Error 2)
3. Getting following error

[image]

Tried multiple time with installation of typescript using npm install typescript as well as npm install -g typescript prior to compile and deploy. but still getting same error. Please find the attachment of the folder structure of my project. Hence I have explicitly moved .vscode folder and its file inside functions folder.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved. I have one missing package that is tslint. So I followed below steps and it has fixed this issue. It was pretty silly one -

1. npm install tslint
2. npm run build

Build will provides all warning and error and I made corresponding changes in package.json.

for more reference find the firebase doc link -
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript